# JQuery JSON Service won't consume

Tags: json, wcf, web-services, jquery

I am trying to consume my newly setup JSON service. I have created a basic fiddle which just alerts when run. As you will see it can't seem to get a response, but when you check the web service URL it is clearly sending a response. 
[http://196.34.92.60/api/api/v1/public.svc/getoperators]

Thanks for the help to the champ who can point out my mistake.

Fiddle address: http://jsfiddle.net/devin85/JmTe4/3/

Cheers Devin

Comment: it is throwing a parsing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Json is invalid so your request is not able to parse. Also if it is from different domain, your datatype should be jsonp.
Change your error to see the issue

```
 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
```

You are asking the url to return a JSON but your json is like this ::     `golden arrowjammiemyciti` which is invalid. SO you need to make your result correct . It can look like this.

```
"result":"golden arrowjammiemyciti"
```

Also if your domain is differnt, you need to change it to JSONP. otherwise do a normal ajax request without any json type.

Comment: This still just returns the text 'error' - fiddle updated - http://jsfiddle.net/devin85/JmTe4/3/

Comment: check this one  http://jsfiddle.net/JmTe4/4/. Also first thing first, make your json proper

Comment: apologies Ashish, I do not understand what you mean by make your "JSON proper". When I view the source of the response it is returning:

Comment: <ResultList xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Developer_Portal" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Results xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <a:string>golden arrow</a:string>
  <a:string>jammie</a:string>
  <a:string>myciti</a:string>
 </Results>
</ResultList>

Comment: json doesnt work that way .  {"Result":"Hello, "}  . It should have format like that Read more on http://json.org/

Comment: I tried a different approach and the error is now more detailed as "200success" on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/devin85/JmTe4/5/ ... Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will implement the changes to the webservice response.